# Trouble converting dates string to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I have a start date that looks like this:

```
var startDate = "Mon Jun 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)";
```

And I am trying to get it formatted into this:

```
var endDate = "2014-06-30T00:00:00-04:00";
```

I have gotten it to semi-format correctly using the toISOString() method:

```
var formattedDate = new Date(startDate);
formattedDate = formattedDate.toISOString();
```

Which formats it into "2014-06-30T04:00:00.000Z". This is close to what I need, but I was wondering if there was built in method to format it into the '-04:00' format? Or do I need to split my string into parts and mend it back together in the right format?

Also I am working out of Google Apps Script, which is ES5, and am trying to avoid jQuery if possible.

Comment: Other than using a library like moment.js you would have to parse the strings yourself and put them back together. Get the `-4:00` from first string and splice it into the toISOString() version

Comment: What format is this? If it's a non-standard you'll have to encode it yourself. See the polyfill example in [the docs for toISOString();](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Polyfill) and change it to your needs!

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). What's the actual problem are you trying to solve? `2014-06-30T00:00:00-04:00` and `2014-06-30T04:00:00.000Z` are identical timestamps. One has a time zone offset and the other is in UTC (`Z`), but they represent the same moment in time and any program that understands [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) will handle that correctly. With that in mind, why do you need the timezone offset?

Comment: @JordanRunning The only reason I need it in that format is because this App I'm entering the dates into requires that format and throws an error with the Z format.

Comment: @MattMcCode Check my answer. Google Apps Script has a built-in method to handle your use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script (GAS) has a built-in utility method you can leverage to format dates:

[`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Its based on Java's [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

To format the date to meet your requirements the following should suffice:

```
var date = new Date("Mon Jun 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)");

var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(
        date, 
        Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
    );
```

Note: You may need to set your script's timezone from the GAS GUI menu via:

**`File->Project Properties->Info`**

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @JordanRunning 's comment.
Still, out of curiosity I quickly put together a way to get your desired format:

```
// two helper functions
function pad(number) {
  if (number < 10) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;
}

function getOffset(offset) {
  if(offset<0) {
    wminutes = 0 - offset;
    var posneg = "-";
  } else {
    wminutes = offset;
    var posneg = "+";
  }
  var hours = pad(Math.floor(wminutes/60));
  var minutes = pad(wminutes % 60);
  return posneg+hours+":"+minutes;
}

// the actual format function
Date.prototype.toMyFormat = function() {
  var format = this.getUTCFullYear() +
    '-' + pad(this.getMonth() + 1) +
    '-' + pad(this.getDate()) +
    'T' + pad(this.getHours()) +
    ':' + pad(this.getMinutes()) +
    ':' + pad(this.getSeconds());

  timezoneOffset = getOffset(this.getTimezoneOffset());
  format += timezoneOffset;
  return format;
}

// usage:
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
   // "2018-11-16T20:53:11.365Z"
console.log(new Date().toMyFormat());
   // "2018-11-16T21:53:11-01:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reformat the string. The format in the OP is consistent with the format specified for [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) in ECMAScript 2018, so you can even reformat that wiht the same function:

```js
// Convert string in DDD MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ format to
// YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ format
function formatDateString(s) {
  var m = {Jan:'01',Feb:'02',Mar:'03',Apr:'04',May:'05',Jun:'06',
           Jul:'07',Aug:'08',Sep:'09',Oct:'10',Nov:'11',Dec:'12'};
  var b = s.split(' ');
  return `${b[3]}-${m[b[1]]}-${b[2]}T${b[4]}${b[5].slice(-5,-2)}:${b[5].slice(-2)}`;      
}

console.log(formatDateString("Mon Jun 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"));

// Not recommended, but it will format any date where its 
// toString method is consistent with ECMAScript 2018
console.log(formatDateString(new Date().toString()));
```